# Competitive programming: Solution runs a bit too slow

Tags: c++, time, time-complexity

[This is a question](http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/2013/zco2013/zco2013-2a.php) from a ZCO (Zonal Computing Olympiad; Indian IOI qualifying contest) paper.

Basically, it revolves around finding the number of distinct pairs of elements from a set of numbers whose sum does not exceed a certain value.

My solution works on all except the last test case (on a certain private server, the test case itself is not available), on which it exceeds the 3-second time limit by half a second.

Am I missing something, algorithmically? A few pointers would be nice.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;

    vector<int> hardness;
    hardness.reserve(n);
    int temp;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        cin >> temp;
        if (temp < k) {
            hardness.push_back(temp);
        }
    }

    sort(hardness.begin(), hardness.end());

    int mx = hardness.back(); //Max element

    int chewableCombinations = 0, cur = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < hardness.size() - 1; ++i) {
        cur = hardness[i];
        if(cur == 0 || cur + mx < k) {
            chewableCombinations += hardness.size() - i - 1;
            continue;
        }
        for(int j = i + 1; j < hardness.size(); ++j) {
            if(cur + hardness[j] < k) {
                ++chewableCombinations;
            } else break; //we've crossed the limit
        }
    }

    cout << chewableCombinations << endl;
}
```

Comment: as @Beta said, you already have them sorted by hardness, so there's no reason to go forward one by one until you find the limit. There's more efficient search algorithms for sorted data.

Comment: Once sorted, it can even be in linear time to find the number of pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If hardness[i]+hardness[j] < k then hardness[i]+hardness[m] < k for all m < j.

You don't have to check them all.